# Footer's positioning causes overlap on other section of the page

Tags: html, css, less

First of all I've gotta say that I looked into topics relevant to mine, but didn't solve the problem.

And what's my problem? I used `position : absolute` & `bottom : 0` to make the footer stick to the bottom of the page. But above that I have a set of widgets! Footer overlaps them. I used `float : left` to make the widgets stay in one line. I tried to clear their float but didn't work. 
Here I provide you with that particular code snippet and the screenshot.

Code Snippet : http://codepen.io/tabibzadeh/pen/AvCow
* Beware that the css is under LESS

[image: screenshot]

Thank you very much :)

Comment: There's a preprocessing error for the code snippet you've supplied.

Comment: Is it just me? I'm getting "757: unexpected token at 'Internal Server Error'"

Answer (score 1):

A website that really helped me out with this sort of issue was the following: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Hopefully that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your efforts and answers.

I was trying your ideas and came up with something new, as said above I removed absolute positioning and applied relative. Then I used `margin-top : 400px`to push down the footer section and it worked! 
But I was wondering if it's a good solution or not?

Thanks again.

Comment: This didn't do it either, the problem was in an internal page where I have a content column. The pushdown in that page was a lot to take in! This trick only works for the homepage as you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Thanks for your efforts. 
It didn't need any positioning. Relative, absolute, etc. 
The solution was to add a `clear:both` to the footer class and apply `margin-top`

Good Luck buddies.

Answer (score 0):

The position:absolute; is forcing your footer on top of your other div's, because you're placing it "absolutely" on said position. Namely; bottom:0. It doesn't care if there's other elements.

Positioning with position:relative; should easily fix this problem.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm

Comment: I changed the positioning of the footer to relative but didn't fix the problem completely. Sticking it to the bottom of the page is still a matter!

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour for `position: absolute` -- The element is positioned absolute with no respect to other elements on the page. If you wish the element to be positioned relatively to the other elements, use `position: relative` (which is the default value). Please note that if you use relative positioning, the parent element and the surrounding elements will affect your styling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `position:absolute` to stick the footer to the bottom of the page. If you want to stick the footer to the bottom of the browser window, then you can use `position:absolute`. But yes it might overlap the content it is happening because your content's height is longer than the browser window's height and you have the footer above the content. That is what you expected by positioning footer like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to the bottom of the body to compensate for the footer height e.g.

```
body{
     padding:0 0 60px;
}
```

If the footer is absolutely positioned within another container then you may need to add the padding to that instead.